# Mysql function TO_SECONDS doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I've been passing through this problem for one day, and it's hard to understand why MySql doesn't work easily.

I'm trying to execute the statement below, but it isn't recognized at all.

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS('2013-09-12 11:15:00');
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION db.to_seconds does not exist

I've checked MySQL's documentation and this function is available since version 5.5. So, I updated my previous version and now I'm working with 6.0 (`Server version: 6.0.4-alpha-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)`) but still not working.

```
mysql> select version();
+---------------------------+
| version()                 |
+---------------------------+
| 6.0.4-alpha-community-log |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: What statement are you trying to execute?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Yeah there is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds `TO_SECONDS() is available beginning with MySQL 5.5.0.`

Comment: Show your `SELECT version()` to be sure that version is correct.

Comment: Done! The select version() is above.

Comment: That new version is an alpha, aka early development version.  If I were you I'd stick to the current GA version (and that's 5.6.13).

Comment: How are you connecting to db becuase your SELECT TO_SECONDS('2013-09-12 11:15:00'); is correct

Comment: @f.v.u Ok thanks, but for now I just wanted to know what is happening with that TO_SECONDS function.

Comment: @KleberSilva: You're using an [alpha version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Alpha).  Maybe it's a bug, maybe it was removed, who knows?  I also suggest using a stable MySQL version.  Who knows what *other* problems you may have with this version.

Comment: It must be the version that you are using because it works on MYSQL 5.6.12

Comment: Okay, I'll try to install another version and will come back here as soon as I can. Thank you so far.

Comment: "alpha" labels are given to the authors to version that are not deemed stable and/or complete enough to be releases.  And that's exactly it's why you should use a recent enough GA release, where the doc as well as people here confirm it works.

Comment: Also have a look [here](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/6.0/en/news-6-0-x.html) - 6.0 isn't referred to on the official Oracle/Mysql site (there 5.7 is current dev version), 6.0 seems to be a very old thing that was never release, and thus despite its high version number it's at least 6 years old and thus predates 5.5 GA.  Dump that junk and use a GA version.  And next time only download from official distribution points :)

Comment: Thank you all! I've installed MySQL 5.5 and is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> TO_SECONDS('2013-09-12 11:15:00');

Seconds are a measure of time interval not a time datum - this therefore implies some sort of reference datum - but when there's lots to choose from, which do you want? One solution is to define your own datum:

SELECT TIME_DIFF('2013-09-12 11:15:00', '01-01-2000 00:00:00')

Or use the Unix epoch:

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-09-12 11:15:00')

Comment: `Given a date or datetime expr, returns a the number of seconds since the year 0.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds

Comment: "....number of seconds since the year 0....is not intended for use with values that precede the advent of the Gregorian calendar (1582)" - Last time I checked 1582 was greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

I was using MySQL version 6.0 that was installed by AppServ (Apache, MySQL, PHP, phpmyadmin) tool and this version of MySQL hasn't support for TO_SECONDS function. After installing MySQL 5.5 it's working perfectly.

```
mysql> select to_seconds('2013-09-02 13:33:59');
+-----------------------------------+
| to_seconds('2013-09-02 13:33:59') |
+-----------------------------------+
|                       63545348039 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```